# REQUEST_URI to set style in active link

Tags: php

I have a menu that i'm including in my site pages, i want to set a style to the active document link in the menu, and this is the way i'm doing that:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="slider.php" title="Slider" class="<?php 
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == ("/cms/app/slider.php")){echo 'active' ;
 }else{ 'not-active';} ?>">Slider</a></li></ul>
```

So, this works as expected, when "slider.php" is an static document, but is not, it could be "slider.php?url=some-slide-in-db" also; or "store.php?id=4" (or any other id number in db), i just don't know how to implement this method in dynamic pages. ¿Can you give me a hand? thanks!

Comment: see $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: i do not understand how to use it...

Comment: i'm understanding now... and testing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sam i used your clue and it works perfect! code:

```
<?php $urlsite=$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; ?>

<li><a href="slider.php" title="Slider" class="<?php 
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == ("/campanario/cms/app/slider.php") | $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == ("/campanario/cms/app/slider_edit.php?$urlsite")){echo 'active' ;}

            else{ 'not-active';} ?>">Slider</a></li>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for your if test.

```
if (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],0,strpos("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) == ("/cms/app/slider.php"))
```

This basically will take the contents of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` up to the first occurance of `?` and use that for your if condition.